# How to better filter the sparql query output to avoid the Query timeout limit reached error?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am getting the Query timeout limit reached error. Is there any way to maybe filter the output more? Thank you!

```
SELECT (count(distinct ?city) as ?count) WHERE {            
            
?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q486972. # human settlement          
?city wdt:P131 ?region.         
?city wdt:P17 ?country.
#not a former country
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240}
#and not an ancient civilisation (needed to exclude ancient Egypt)
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q28171280}
#not demolished, abolished countries etc.
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P576 ?abolished}
?article schema:about ?city.            
?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.           
            
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the what is the intention of this query? Specifically, the comments suggest that you want to exclude certain countries by the navigation clause `NOT EXISTS` will test for the absence of the pattern(s) and will "filter" exactly those. 
Also for this specific count, you don't need the last two triple patterns.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. The intention is just to see how many cities as described in the query exist in Wikidata. I assume the output is too big, and that is why it returns the error..

Comment: As for NOT EXISTS filter, yes, I would like to see the cities that are mapped to present-day countries only.

Comment: You reach a time out error because the query is semantical not correct. You need to group your data in order to use aggregated functions in SPARQL. Try for example
Select ?country (count (distinct ?city) as ?count) where {Pattern} Group by ?country